# Python ffmpeg won't accept path, why?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

everytime i launch the code and set the correct path it gives me this error, I tried including ffmpeg path, uninstalling and installing the library back but no luck. I've also tried using diffrent ways to set the path like putting it directly without saving it to a variable, this is getting me crazy please help me with a solution .

---

```
                                                     Code
```

---

```
from pytube import *
import ffmpeg

global str
userurl = (input("Enter a youtube video URL : "))
q = str(input("Which quality you want ?  360p,480p,720p,1080p,4K,Flh :")).lower()
yt = YouTube(userurl)
print ("Title of the video : ",yt.title)


def hd1080p():
    print("Downloading a HD 1080p video...")
    v = yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4", res="1080p", adaptive = True).first().download(filename = "HD1080P.mp4")
    print("Video downloaded")
    yt.streams.filter(mime_type="audio")
    a = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
    print("Downloading audio")
    a.download(filename = "audio.mp4")
    print("audio downloaded")
    input_video = ffmpeg.input("HD1080P.mp4")
    added_audio = ffmpeg.input("audio.mp4").audio.filter('adelay', "1500|1500")

    merged_audio = ffmpeg.filter([input_video.audio, added_audio], 'amix')

    (
        ffmpeg
        .concat(input_video, merged_audio, v=1, a=1)
        .output("mix_delayed_audio.mp4")
        .run(overwrite_output=True)
    )
    

if q == "1080" or q == "1080p":
    hd1080p()
elif q == "720" or q == "720p":
    hd720p()
elif q == "480" or q == "480p":
    l480p()
elif q == "360" or q == "360p":
    l360p()
elif q ==  "4" or q == "4k":
    hd4k()
else:
    print("invalid choice")
```

---

```
                                                  THE ERROR
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\messa\Desktop\upcoming project\videodownloader.py", line 65, in <module>
    hd1080p()
  File "c:\Users\messa\Desktop\upcoming project\videodownloader.py", line 26, in hd1080p
    ffmpeg
  File "E:\Users\messa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "E:\Users\messa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "E:\Users\messa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "E:\Users\messa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path? For example: "C:/Users/username/file.mp4"

Comment: yeah @SaladHead

Comment: Is ffmpeg installed? Where is it? What is the current directory? Is the ffmpeg path in the `PATH` environment variable? Does ffmpeg work if you execute it directly in a terminal?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón i don't know understand what you are saying but i installed it using pip3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution in Windows OS, is placing `ffmpeg.exe` in the same folder as the Python script.

The reason you are getting the error, is that `ffmpeg.exe` is not in the execution path of your operating system.
Note: Executing `pip install ffmpeg-python` does not download FFmpeg application (but the Python package requires FFmpeg executable for functioning).

Assuming you are using Windows:

You can install `FFmpeg` as descried here: [How to Install FFmpeg on Windows](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows).

My suggestion:

- Download the latest stable release from https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases.
  Static build in preferred (static build applies single executable file).
  You may download a GPL licensed version (GPL versus LGPL is not relevant for executables).
  The latest stable release up to date (Jan 23 2021) is 4.3.1
  Assuming you are using Windows x64, download: `ffmpeg-n4.3.1-29-g89daac5fe2-win64-gpl-4.3.zip`
- Extract the ZIP file, and copy `ffmpeg.exe` to the same folder as your Python script.
- In case it's working, you may also put `ffmpeg.exe` someplace else (like `C:\ffmpeg\bin\`), and update the Windows path.

---

### Update:

There is an option to execute `ffmpeg.exe`, without adding it to the system path.

The method `ffmpeg.run()` accepts the optional argument `cmd`.
The default value of `cmd` is `ffmpeg`.
You can set the value of `cmd` to the full execution path.

Example:

```
(
    ffmpeg
    .concat(input_video, merged_audio, v=1, a=1)
    .output("mix_delayed_audio.mp4")
    .run(overwrite_output=True, cmd=r'c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe')
)
```

Comment: Your welcome. I just edited the post - there is also an option to set `cmd` argument.

Comment: "Assuming you are using Windows:"... and for those of us that are on Mac?....

Comment: @BrandonA Look for instructions: [Installing FFmpeg on Mac](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-mac). (you may search Google for instructions). I don't have an access to a Mac, and I don't know if there are any issues you are going to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

You ffmpeg isn't installed in the correct path and or your environmental variables arent setup correctly.  Here's the quickest fix.

**STEP 1**
Rename the extracted folder to ffmpeg and move it into the root of C: drive.

**STEP 2**
Run cmd as an administrator and set the environment path variable for ffmpeg by running the following command: setx /m PATH "C:\ffmpeg\bin;%PATH%"

**STEP 3**
restart computer then check pip again with version -ffmpeg to make sure its correctly installed.