# Error merging audio and video ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

So I'm trying to merge audio and video using ffmpeg-python but it keeps telling me one error

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Here's the code that im trying

```
def videoAudio():
    input_video = ffmpeg.input('./ONLYVIDEO.mp4')
    input_audio = ffmpeg.input('./ONLYAUDIO.webm')
    ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output('./complete.mp4').run()
```

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Comment: What is the absolute path to the video and audio, what is your working directory, and what does `videoName` and `audioName` contain ?

Comment: Look again at the code i tried another thing at it gives the same error but much cleaner code

Comment: We still need the path to the folder where your script was executed from, and the absolute path to both the audio and video files

Comment: C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python, they are in the same folder

C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\mergeFiles.py
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\ONLYAUDIO.webm
C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\ONLYVIDEO.mp4

Comment: ... Please add a `import os; print(os,getcwd())` to your code …

Comment: <module 'os' from 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\os.py'> C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python

Comment: And im on windows 10 in visual studio code

Comment: Weird … What happens if you use the complete paths ? (`C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\ONLYVIDEO.mp4`, `C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\ONLYAUDIO.webm`)

Comment: def videoAudio():
    input_video = ffmpeg.input('C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\ONLYVIDEO.mp4')
    input_audio = ffmpeg.input('C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\ONLYAUDIO.webm')
    ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output('C:\Users\angel\Desktop\python\complete.mp4').run()

So like ther¡s a problem doing this because the path contains "\a" and pyhton interprets that like unicode and give me error:SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: The system cannot find `ffmpeg.exe` (command line tool). See: [Python ffmpeg won't accept path, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-why).

Comment: It works, I installed ffmpeg, put it in the path folder of windows and put ffmpeg.exe in the python folder and it works, thanks bro you saved me

Comment: Ahh, that was a good point @Rotem, without you we would have continued to check on the files location and eventually ended up without a solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter here to download ffmpeg.exe, you have to have it where you're executing the script.
[Python ffmpeg won't accept path, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-why)

Look UP at the comments section of the question to see more information