# ffmpeg-python output gives file not found error

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mpdecimate

I am trying out mpdecimate using ffmpeg-python library https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/.

However, I get a file not found error for the simple code below.

```
def remove_duplicate_ffmpeg(video_file_path,out_video_file_path):
    out, err = (
        ffmpeg
        .input(video_file_path)
        .filter('mpdecimate')
        .output(out_video_file_path)
        .run()
    )
    return out
```

Comment: where do you define video_file_path and where do you call remove_duplicate_ffmpeg -- Give me code I can run and get the same error you are saying you are getting. If I copy what you have here then write other stuff to implement it, assuming I know what I am doing and how to answer your question, then it is reasonably going to work because I am going to write it correctly haha.

Comment: It looks like `ffmpeg-python` cannot find FFmpeg command line tools. Check the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-why) post.