# How to convert webm/mp4 file to mp3 with ffmpeg in a script (pycharm)?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pycharm, type-conversion

I'm working on a YouTube-Downloader project and I'm having issues with my audio files.
My code uses pytube to download the audio from a video.

The problem is that the downloaded audio file is either a .webm or a .mp4 file, which I'd like to convert to a .mp3 file.
Is there a way to read the filetype (webm/mp4) first and then run a code that converts it to a mp3 file?

I'd like to run it as a script in pycharm. Not as a command in the console.

Thanks for your answers.

Das Typ

Comment: yes. `str.endswith` and call ffmpeg with `subprocess.run`

Comment: `yt-dlp` could do all the steps for you. There is no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried it with 'ffmpeg -i input.webm output.mp3' but there is always an error that says something like: The command "ffmpeg" is either misspelled or could not be found. Same problem with yt-dlp since it seems like it uses ffmpeg too. How can I solve this? (I've installed ffmpeg over 'pip install ffmpeg')

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed ffmpeg correctly,and set the environment path for it.

For windows;

1. Install ffmpeg from [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
2. Extract it under the root directory C:\
3. Set the environment path variable by typing this command in your cmd

   ```
   setx /m PATH "C:\ffmpeg\bin;%PATH%"
   ```

Be sure that the extracted folder name is ffmpeg

(You can test if it is installed by typing this into cmd:)

```
ffmpeg -version
```

Now you can use ffmpeg from cmd by running subprocess module:

```
import subprocess

path = '[yourmp4fileaddress]'

subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i "path/filename".mp4 "filename".mp3',shell=True)
```

just in case in you want to print the output of the above command in your compiler:

```
import subprocess

path = '[yourpathaddress]'

print(subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i "path/filename".mp4 "filename".mp3',shell=True,capture_output=True))
```

Comment: more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-why/65860115#65860115)

Comment: what does the ```-i``` flag mean? I tried ```ffmpeg -help```, but it says nothing about it

Comment: `-i ` : input parameter