# Cannot install ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to install ffmpeg
When I run `import matplotlib.animation as animation print(animation.writers.list())`
I get ['pillow', 'html']

I have donwloaded from website and run in command promt
`C:\Users\->pip install ffmpeg Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg in c:\users\-\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.4)`

When I run my code I get below error:
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

Note: I write on Hupyter via Anaconda

Comment: have you installed an FFmpeg binary? see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-why/65860115#65860115)

Answer (score 0):

right name is ffmpeg-python :

conda install ffmpeg-python

or

pip install ffmpeg-python

https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: Thank you. I get a already satisifed for pip. Conda- 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.